# Can't unsubscribe from ngrx store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I really confused with next situation. Maybe I don't understand something in browser.

I have a Subscription to select from my ngrx/entity store. It works good. Code below.

```html
constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.formConfiguration();

    this.moveTradeSubscription = this.store.select(selectTradeEntities).subscribe((tradeDictionary) => {
      const tradeFromStore = Object.values(tradeDictionary)[0];
      if (tradeFromStore !== null && tradeFromStore !== undefined && tradeFromStore.Stage === 2) {
        // this.store.dispatch(removeTrade());
        console.log('remove from panel draft stage 2');
        this.tradeDraftPanelEmitter.emit(tradeFromStore.TradeId);
        this.store.dispatch(deleteTrade({ TradeId: tradeFromStore.TradeId }));
      }
    })
  }
```

And you can see I have `console.log('remove from panel draft stage 2');`

Also I `unsubscribe` from my `Subscription`

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.moveTradeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

But I have always repeat this `console.log('remove from panel draft stage 2');` after destroy of component and the most strange after reload and close and open again browser.

[image]

After reload of my page.

[image]

As I understand I didn't `unsubscribe`

Comment: Your controller implements OnDestroy?

Comment: Yes, of course I have it `implements OnInit, OnDestroy`

Comment: Could you share more details about the implementation? Where is the place where you call this part that registry the subscription? Construtor? ngOnInit?

Comment: it seems you are dispatching inside of a subscribtion to a selector which causes an event to that selector again and again recursively. is that intended?

Comment: I'd use `takeUntilDestroy()` instead.

Comment: @DiogoMachado I updated the question. You can find the constructor

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler did't help.

Comment: Are you sure the component is really destroyed? Maybe it's just hidden? For example if you're using some tabs that hide UI instead of destroying. Did you try to simply add console.log('Component is destroyed') to ngOnDestroy? Maybe it wasn't called at all.

Comment: Totally agree @alexdefender93, you can try to check with the developer tools, in the source tab, find the ngOnDestroy and set a breakpoint, then you can check if the event is called or not, maybe you are not changing the route.

Answer (score 0):

give type moveTradeSubscription !: Subscription

Subscription  comes from rxjs

and
second one use

this.store.select(selectTradeEntities).pipe(take(1)).subscribe() => ...continue with your code
you will use take , takeUntill accoding to you